# does the user need to be logged in to be able to use the in-app purchase functionality?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, in-app-purchase

Being quite a beginner in the field of app development...

I am trying to understand if the user needs to log in to the mobile app for being able to purchase anything (with in-app purchases)? With other words, can I implement the in-app purchases functionality in the app without requiring the user to log in to the app? I could not make this clear to me in the docs so far..

How does the answer change if the app is an IOS app or an Android app?

Also, if it is not required that the user will be logged in... Is it still recommended that it is implemented in that way that the user first logs in? If yes, why..?

Note: I am implementing my app with Ionic 4 (Angular).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, does not matters if your user is logged or not. Do you need to keep a pair between a user and a purchase? If answer is yes you need to keep some way to pair users with purchases. You can implement a simple way to buy something without log,  but in my opinion, maybe not now but I am sure that in near future you will want to keep users info in your system. Keep in mind the future of your app, not only the present. Tell us a bit more :)

Comment: thanks for the answer. Simply, the app provides a certain content given in a table format. The user is supposed to buy credits for being able to see the content in each row. Say that the user buys 20 credits and needs to spend 4 credits for seeing each row. My intention is to use the Ionic Offline Storage functionality (with sqLite) to remember how many credits the user has at a given time. I agree with you though that I may need the user to be logged in for another reason. I use Firestore and want to limit nr of reads/writes as well to minimize the cost of it.That's the dilemma